GCP Speech-to-text AsyncClient with FastAPI and python-socketio
I am trying to build a FastAPI socket server that receives sound chunks as bytes using the python-socketio library and sends them to the Google Cloud Platform Speech-to-text API.
For now, I haven't been able to get it working. The example displayed in the documentation implements a microphone stream directly in the code so the websocket part is not present. The last error message I've got on a loop (until i get an UNAVAILABLE:GOAWAY error for client_misbehavior) is:
Connection pool is full, discarding connection: oauth2.googleapis.com. Connection pool size: 10
Here is a simplified version of the server code:

import asyncio
import io
import json
from google.cloud.speech_v1 import (
    SpeechAsyncClient,
    RecognitionConfig,
    StreamingRecognitionConfig,
    StreamingRecognizeRequest,
)

from main import sio

audio_queue = asyncio.Queue()
stop_audio_stream = True

client = SpeechAsyncClient()

streaming_config = StreamingRecognitionConfig(
    config=RecognitionConfig(
    encoding=RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
    sample_rate_hertz=16000,
    language_code="fr-FR"
    ),
    interim_results=True
)

async def request_generator():
        yield StreamingRecognizeRequest(streaming_config=streaming_config)

        chunk = await audio_queue.get()
        if chunk is None:
            return
        data = [chunk]

        while True:
            try:
                chunk = audio_queue.get(block=False)
                if chunk is None:
                    return
                data.append(chunk)
            except audio_queue.Empty:
                break

        joined_data = b"".join(data)
        yield StreamingRecognizeRequest(audio_content=joined_data)

async def recognize(requests):
    responses = await client.streaming_recognize(requests)
    async for response in responses:
        try: 
            for result in response.results:
                data = {
                'alternatives': [{
                    'transcript': alternative.transcript,
                    'confidence': alternative.confidence
                } for alternative in result.alternatives],
                'is_final': result.is_final
            }
            yield f"{json.dumps(data)}\n"
        except Exception as e:
            raise e

class SocketIORoutes:
    @sio.on("connect", namespace="/api/")
    async def connect(sid, environ):
        print("Connection (sid: {})".format(sid))

    @sio.on("audio_data", namespace="/api/")
    async def audio_data(sid, audio_data_msg):
    
        audio_data = io.BytesIO(audio_data_msg)

        try:
            await audio_queue.put(audio_data)
            requests = request_generator()
            transcripts = recognize(requests)
            async for transcript in transcripts:
                print(transcript)

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            raise

    @sio.on("disconnect", namespace="/api/")
    async def disconnect(sid):
        await.emit('bye', namespace="/api/")

I am both new to ASGI and websockets. I've monitored the pace rate of the socketio requests between the frontend and the server (the frontend from which the microphone stream is sent is not mine and I cannot change it) and there are a LOT of requests per second. My guess is that the errors come from the speed at which my iterators are making the requests to the GCP API, and that I should control the size and pace of the chunks I am sending to the STT API but I don't really know how.
I've tried getting inspiration from this repo or this repo but the first one transmits the audio data as a whole file through an http endpoint, and the second one uses threads and I haven't found a way to adapt it to FastAPI.
Any help deeply appreciated, thank you.

Do you have server logs? You aren't really describing what the error(s) are, and you are also not showing what the frontend does, so there's a lot of information that is missing.
